# Speed, time, distance and Turn Navigation (Left -Right)

Tags: here-api

I have integrated the turn - turn Navigation with the help of https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples. 
But I am not finding the code as turnManeuver true left -right, speed, locationtname etc as per below image.

I also read this document https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/map-guidance.html. But I am not getting more details of turn left right , speed, time.

- **Navigation is working fine.**
- **Need to code top bar as write NMAManeuver left, right, name ,distance etc**
- **Need to code bottom bar as speed, time distance**

Please provide me some source code which help I can integration as per image. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Providing the entire application source for this feature is outside of the scope of StackOverflow. You could request this extension from the HERE team on GitHub. But to get you started, you are already looking in all the right places, it's just a matter of reading a little more documentation.

- **NMAManeuver left, right, name, distance etc**: You can get `NMANavigationManager::nextManeuver`, the returned `NMAManeuver` object has all the info you want, e.g. `roadName`, `nextRoadName`, `distanceFromPreviousManeuver`, `roadName`, ...
- **speed, time distance**: See `NMANavigationManager::averageSpeed`, `timeToArrival`, `distanceToDestination`

More Info:

- [NMANavigationManager API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmanavigationmanager.html)
- [NMAManeuver API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmamaneuver.html)

Comment: Thanks I got .  For turn self.navigationManager.nextManeuver.turn ==(3)  retunAny Integer value. For Turn Left ,right etc. I will be given condition according this or any way to writing code for turning 

 if (self.navigationManager.nextManeuver.turn ==3)
    {
        turningLbl.text = @" Turn Keep Right";
        
    }